# python: covert a file into a list of list of string

Tags: python

a file contains informaton like below
I'd like to covert this file into list of list of string
There is a blank line between group.

```
pear
banana

milk
tea
coffee
```

and the result returns:

```
build_list(f):
[[pear, banana], [milk, tea, coffee]]
```

Comment: I am thinking about geting rid of the blank line between each group. But so far my code is not working.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
with open("data.txt") as f:
    res = [line.split('\n') for line in f.read().split('\n\n')]
```

Split the input data into groups then split each group into lines.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
from itertools import groupby

def build_list(name):
    with open(name, "r") as f:
        return [[i.strip() for i in group] for key, group in
                groupby(f, key=lambda k: (k.strip() == "")) if not key]
```

This solution will even allow for degenerate files where you have more than one empty line between groups or multiple empty lines at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Stack_13328928.txt is your list. Please note that the last line in your input file has to be a new line, otherwise the last item is lost, but I think the code can be modified that you don't need a blank new line.

```
import csv
in_file = open("stack_13328928.txt")
CSV = csv.reader(in_file)
outer_ls = []
inter_ls = []
for i in CSV:
    try:
        i[0]
        inter_ls += i
    except:
        outer_ls.append(inter_ls)
        inter_ls = []

print outer_ls
```